# Type not assignable on Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning `React` so I've crafted a little app around `Github` API, I'm trying to list all the user repositories, so I've created a `RepoItem` component which contains the following structure:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface RepoItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  html_url: string;
}

export const RepoItem = ({ repo }: RepoItem) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h3>
        <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

then, I have the `Repos` component that call `RepoItem` as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { RepoItem } from './repoItem';

interface Repos {
  repos: Array<RepoItem>;
}

export const Repos = ({ repos }: Repos) => {
  return repos.map((repo: RepoItem) => <RepoItem repo={repo} key={repo.id} />);
};
```

the problem's that on this line `<RepoItem repo={repo}`

I get:

> Type '{ repo: RepoItem; key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RepoItem'.
> Property 'repo' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RepoItem'.

what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```js
export const RepoItem = ({ repo }: RepoItem) => {
```

with

```js
export const RepoItem = ({ repo } : { repo: RepoItem }) => {
```

or

```js
export const RepoItem: React.FC<{ repo: RepoItem }> = ({ repo }) => {
```

Otherwise, you're typing the `props` object, not `props.repo`.

Comment: if I apply your solution I get: `Binding element 'RepoItem' implicitly has an 'any' type.` are u sure about that?

Comment: @sfarzoso Sorry about that. I've added the correct options.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you just simply create a `Props` for your component then add `React.SFC<Props>` as return value which is the most correct one:

```js
import React from 'react';

export interface RepoItem {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  html_url: string;
}

interface Props {
  repo: RepoItem
}

export const RepoItem: React.SFC<Props> = ({ repo }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h3>
        <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Likewise for other components but keep in mind, `SFC` for stateless and `FC` for stateful

Comment: Seems SFC is deprecated

Comment: Yeah seems it's replaced for a better meaning `StatelessComponent` but it's not a big deal at all